# Why is the mini program failing to open when I scan the QR code from my camera?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I generated a QR code for the mini program I am developing, from the workspace and tried scanning it from my iPhone camera. I am getting the following error message: “no usable data found”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only open generated QR codes from within the Vodapay app’s inbuilt QR code scanner found on the bottom nav-bar, labeled ‘Pay’.